# How to search for node using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Lets say I have this html:

```
<table class="c1">
<tr>
<td>Dog</td>
<td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog">Dog</a><td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cat</td>
<td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat">Cat</a><td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I tried:

```
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='c1']");
HtmlNodeCollection urls = node.SelectNodes("a");
```

the `node` have the table but `urls` is null. Why?

Comment: `//table[@class='c1']//a` should work in one shot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  `Descendants("a")` instead of `SelectNodes("a");`

This should work....

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='c1']");
var  urls = node.Descendants("a").ToList();
```

Comment: `Descendants("a")` is what I needed... `SelectNodes("//a")` was not searching in the `node` it was searching all document for `"a"`

Comment: `SelectNodes("a")` is not working either.. I tried it (look my question)